# Pointer macros are not functioning

Tags: c++, header-files, spdlog

I am making a logging system for an engine I am building and have run into an issue. I set up a number of macros for my engine but unfortunately, they don't seem to work.
here is my code:
Log.cpp

```
#include "Log.h"
#include "spdlog/sinks/stdout_color_sinks.h"

namespace Divided
{
    std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> Log::s_CoreLogger;
    std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> Log::s_ClientLogger;

    void Log::Init()
    {
        spdlog::set_pattern("%^[%T] %n: %v%$");
        s_CoreLogger = spdlog::stdout_color_mt("DIVIDED");
        s_CoreLogger->set_level(spdlog::level::trace);
        s_ClientLogger = spdlog::stdout_color_mt("APP");
        s_ClientLogger->set_level(spdlog::level::trace);
    }
}
```

Log.h

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include "Core.h"
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"

namespace Divided
{
    class DIVIDED_API Log
    {
    public:
        static void Init();

        inline static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger>& GetCoreLogger() { return s_CoreLogger; }
        inline static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger>& GetClientLogger() { return s_ClientLogger; }
    private:
        static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> s_CoreLogger;
        static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> s_ClientLogger;
    };
}

//core logging macros
#define DV_CORE_FATAL(...) ::Divided::Log::GetCoreLogger->fatal(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DV_CORE_ERROR(...) ::Divided::Log::GetCoreLogger->error(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DV_CORE_WARN(...)  ::Divided::Log::GetCoreLogger->warn(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DV_CORE_INFO(...)  ::Divided::Log::GetCoreLogger->info(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DV_CORE_TRACE(...) ::Divided::Log::GetCoreLogger->trace(__VA_ARGS__)
                           ::
//client logging macros    ::
#define DV_FATAL(...)      ::Divided::Log::GetClientLogger->fatal(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DV_ERROR(...)      ::Divided::Log::GetClientLogger->error(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DV_WARN(...)       ::Divided::Log::GetClientLogger->warn(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DV_INFO(...)       ::Divided::Log::GetClientLogger->info(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DV_TRACE(...)      ::Divided::Log::GetClientLogger->trace(__VA_ARGS__)
```

and core.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef DV_PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    #ifdef DV_BUILD_DLL
        #define DIVIDED_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define DIVIDED_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else
    #error DIVIDED ONLY SUPPORTS WINDOWS!
#endif
```

when i call any of the macros visual studio says that left of  `->` must point to a data type. does any one know why this is braking

Comment: `GetCoreLogger->` should be `GetCoreLogger()->` - you need to call the function

Comment: why do you use macros ? If you had used `__FILE__` or `__LINE__` i would understand but without I dont see the advantage of macros

Comment: @UnholySheep thank you. not quite sure how I forgot that

Comment: Aren't you wrapping an already good logger into something unnecessary with that `shared_ptr` ? Won't `spdlog::info("...");` etc. work straight out the box?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes. but i don't much care for the format the spdlog uses so i wanted to change it to something that i prefer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution here is really quite trivial. the way that the macros are defined now they will be a pointer to a function that is trying to call what should be a member function. this obviously will not work. what must be done is to add parentheses to the end of every call of `GetClientLogger` and `GetCoreLogger` so that the return type of these functions--classes--will call their correct and existing member functions.